# Login with Facebook leaves me with an empty blank page in Facebook

Tags: facebook, authentication, oauth

Using Facebook oauth, that actually worked for the past 4 years until recently.
Behaviour:

- User redirected to Facebook oauth method;
- User remains in Facebook page with blank page;

It should have redirected back to my page, but instead, it stays at facebook and does nothing, no error, nothing.